# Determine inheritance at compile time

Tags: c++

I have some code that behaves like this:

```
class Base {};

class MyClass : public Base {};

MyClass* BaseToMyClass(Base* p)
{
  MyClass* pRes = dynamic_cast<MyClass*>(p);
  assert(pRes);
  return pRes;
}
```

Is there a way to add a compile time check so I can catch calls to this function where p is not an instance of MyClass?  I had a look at Alexandrescu's SUPERSUBCLASS function but I'm not sure if it can do the job.

Thanks!

Comment: As if we're all meant to know what "Alexandrescu's SUPERSUBCLASS function" is...

Comment: @Noldorin, it's pretty common, check out "Modern C++ design: generic programming and design patterns applied" by Andrei Alexandrescu:  http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0201704315

Comment: Nonetheless, it's far from common kowledge, and thus should be specified.

Comment: @Noldoring @liaK: If you don't understand the question and are not willing to try, you are perfectly free to just pass. I do it frequently because I just don't want to lose my time. On the other hand, I happen to know Alexandrescu so I would be more inclined to check my copy of Modern C++ Design (if I were at home).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to add a compile time check so I can catch calls to this function where p is not an instance of MyClass?

Generally, if you want to check this at compile-time, you'd take the derived class as an argument.

However, if the only thing you have is a `Base*` or a `Base&`, then ***you cannot know*** whether it refers to a `MyClass` object. It's the very nature of ***run-time*** polymorphism that this is to be found out at ***run-time***. This check can only be done where the `MyClass` object/reference/pointer is converted to a `Base*`/`Base&`. That's why `dynamic_cast<>()` was invented.

Your function basically is a `safe_cast`. If you put it into the right syntax, it looks like this:

```
template< typename Derived, typename Base >
inline Derived* safe_cast(Base* pb)
{
  #if defined _NDEBUG
    return static_cast<Derived*>(pb);
  #else
    Derived* pd = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pb);
    assert(pd);
    return pd;
  #endif
}

template< typename Derived, typename Base >
inline Derived& safe_cast(Base& rb)
{
  return *safe_cast<Derived*>(&rb);
}
```

Comment: I get a pointer to Base which I need to convert to MyClass. The pointer is supposed to always be an instance of MyClass, but mistakes happen, so I would like to check compile time that this pointer is indeed a pointer to MyClass. This is a large amount of legacy code. It is not realistic to change existing code to pass MyClass around instead of Base.

Comment: @user72185: I've added some information regarding this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base() {} };

struct MyClass : public Base {};

template <class T> MyClass* BaseToMyClass(T p) {
    int x[-(int)sizeof(T)];
    return 0;
}

template <> MyClass* BaseToMyClass(Base* p) {
    printf("1\n");
    MyClass* pRes = dynamic_cast<MyClass*>(p);
    assert(pRes != NULL);
    return pRes;
}
```

If the function is called with `Base*`, the 1st specialization will be used. If it is called with `MyClass*`, the generic version will be used. Since an array cannot have negative size, this will cause a compile-time error, which can be traced back to the point of instantiation.

The `sizeof(T)` is to ensure the error is shown only at instantiation time.

Note that this method is not suitable if `Base` has any other subclasses you want to pass.

---

Example usage:

```
int main () {           // 22
    MyClass p;          // 23
    Base q;             // 24
    BaseToMyClass(&q);  // 25
    BaseToMyClass(&p);  // 26
}                       // 27
```

Results in

```
x.cpp: In function 'MyClass* BaseToMyClass(T) [with T = MyClass*]':
x.cpp:26:22:   instantiated from here
x.cpp:11:27: error: creating array with negative size ('-0x00000000000000008')
```

Note that it cannot detect what the pointer is `new`-ed with. For instance, in

```
int main () {
    Base* p = new Base;
    Base* q = new MyClass;
    BaseToMyClass(p);
    BaseToMyClass(q);
    delete p;
    delete q;
}
```

the program will be compiled successfully.

Comment: It is always called with Base, I just want to know (compile time) if this instance of base was created as new MyClass or new Base.  The second option would be an error, but I would only catch it at run time. I'm working with a lot of legacy code so I have to live with what I get. Having a compile time check would be awesome, since I cannot know if I get all code paths tested.

Comment: @user: You can't know in compile-time whether the variable is created as `new MyClass` or `new Base` *if* your code is like `Base* p = new Something`. Compile-time check only know `p` is of type `Base*`. But it can catch `Something* p = new Something`.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm posting this as a different answer since the strategy is different.)

You could use a static assert for a more flexible constraint, e.g.

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

template <class T>
MyClass* BaseToMyClass(T* x) {
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(!(boost::is_convertible<T, MyClass>::value));
    // ^ This ensures T is not MyClass at compile time.

    MyClass* p = dynamic_cast<MyClass*>(x);
    assert(p);
    return p;
}
```

The error message looks like

```
x.cpp: In function 'MyClass* BaseToMyClass(T*) [with T = MyClass]':
x.cpp:26:22:   instantiated from here
x.cpp:13:1: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>'
```

Note that, it also *cannot* detect if you declare a pointer as `Base* p = new MyClass`.

This code uses [Boost.StaticAssert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) and [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html). The former can be replaced by the built-in `static_assert` in C++0x, while the latter is available as a built-in library since TR1.